# How to start android avd emulator in terminal

Tags: react-native, android-virtual-device

When I want to execute `react-native run-android` in terminal, I must open android studio and run android emulator first, It's tricky. Someone knows how to run android emulator in terminal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under your sdk install location there is a directory called tools. From there you can run;

```
$ ./emulator -avd my-android-image
```